# MVC 3 project rejects requests for Razor views with CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7-x64

I have and MVC3 project that once upon a time was an MVC2 project. I've been developing it using IIS express to test.
Now I deployed it to IIS proper on my machine, jiggled some web.config settings, and messed around for an hour getting the razor build provider to be registered, which must not be done right because the new project template doesn't include a line adding that build provider in the web.config.

At any rate, any time I go to a strongly-typed Razor view I get this:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 1:  @model Cairn.Cartography.Features.Peak
```

Any thoughts on what is going on, and how I might fix it without firebombing this box and looking around for my windows install cd? :)

Comment: use Web Platform installer to check that MVC3 is installed on the target machine.

Comment: Yeah, the weird thing is that it is. But the assemblies aren't in the GAC (I'm not sure if they are supposed to be?). Maybe something got installed in the wrong order, or maybe that isn't even the problem anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was missing:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

in this part of my web.config file:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="Cairn"/>
      <add namespace="Cairn.UI.Web"/>
      <add namespace="Cairn.UI.Web.Helpers"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I haven't the foggiest what this means or why it matters, or why it is absent from the web.config generated for a brand new project, but it works.

? Oh well

Comment: And now I can run in IIS proper, and now I can run in a 64-bit process, and now I can load the library I need, and it all falls into place. :)

Comment: Please note that this is the web.config in the Views directory (or in \Areas\Foo\Views\). After some refactoring I also was missing the <host /> bit there.

Answer (score 2):

yes.. reinstall asp.net MVC3 again

either get the MSI file from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208140

or use Web Platform Installer from here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3